# How can i change order position of swatch in ascending Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, sort

I want to change the sort order of size swatches.

I have already put it in sort order from admin but I could not see any result in the front side.

**Actual Result**

[image]
[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

**How can I sort it as per my expected result.**

Comment: Did you try indexing?

Comment: yes, I have clear cache and reindex @Divyarajsinh

Comment: Now you can not see result in frontend. For that you need to customize code or else delete attribute and create new with proper sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Yo! Yo!
Find a Solution!
Also see
[Swatch Option Not showing in ASC order in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262579/swatch-option-not-showing-asc-order-in-magento2/273328#273328)

Open File

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/OptionSelectBuilder.php

Add Below code on after line no. 93
`)->joinInner(
    ['attribute_option' => $this->attributeResource->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
    'attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value',
    []
)->order('attribute_option.sort_order ASC'`

[image]

**Note: You need to set position of swatch in admin**

Comment: right answer! minus point lol