# Swatch Option Not showing in ASC order in Magento2

Tags: magento2, swatches

If size swatch not found with color swatch then it showing in last position, But I want to show in ascending order.
Any way for this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yo! Yo!
Find a Solution!

Open File

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/OptionSelectBuilder.php

Add Below code on after line no. 93
`)->joinInner(
    ['attribute_option' => $this->attributeResource->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
    'attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value',
    []
)->order('attribute_option.sort_order ASC'`

[image]

[image]

**Note: You need to set position of swatch in admin**